# Not listing the file specified in regex with fnmatch

Tags: glob, fnmatch

I am trying to list only specified files in my directory but getting only empty results. When I checked the expected results with regex tester (https://regex101.com/), I've got the expected results.

[image]

But in the python code, I can see nothing.

I tried some other combinations in regex string but nothing helped. I can list the whole directory though.

Am I doing something wrong ? It looks like quite simple solution so what am I missing ?

Code here:

```
import os
import fnmatch

directory = 'output/'

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, '^[20]+[0-9]+\.xlsx$'):
        print(filename)
```

Can you please have a look and give me some hint ?

Many thanks

Comment: `fnmatch` does not support regex.

Answer (score 0):

OK guys, thanks Wiktor for your reply. After that I look for a workaround and I came with this.

```
x = re.search("^[20]+[0-9]+\.xlsx$", filename)
            if x is not None:
                print(filename)
```

I am getting satisfying result so I think, I can close this one.

Many thaanks.